# How to disable all widgets inside Panel or inside Composite?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a composite widget, which contain many widgets (inside `HorizontalPanel`). How to disable all widgets inside `HorizontalPanel` or inside this composite? I can't find `setEnabled()` method in `Composite` or panels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is to recursively get all children of the panel and call `setEnabled(false)` on each widget, which extends `FocusWidget`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've already figured it out, but if anyone else is curious, this will enable or disable all nested FocusWidgets:

```
private void enableAllChildren(boolean enable, Widget widget)
{
    if (widget instanceof HasWidgets)
    {
        Iterator<Widget> iter = ((HasWidgets)widget).iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            Widget nextWidget = iter.next();
            enableAllChildren(enable, nextWidget);
            if (nextWidget instanceof FocusWidget)
            {
                ((FocusWidget)nextWidget).setEnabled(enable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's enough to cast to `HasEnabled` interface instead of `FocusWidget`

Comment: I get "Incompatible conditional operand types Widget and HasWidgets" with your code.

Answer (score 1):

getWidget() method of Composite class is protected, hence you cant access widgets inside composite from outside packages. Hence you can not get children widgets of Composite without subclassing Composite.