# Gwt Disable Mouse Clicking While Request is Pending

Tags: java, gwt

I am writing a GWT App and use AsyncCallBack to send request to my server. The problem which I have not solved is that while I am waiting for response from server it is possible to click on other tab of my app. I would like to disable clicking on other elements while response is completely received. Could you please, advise me is there a solution for this issue? Code to comunicate with server is:

```
     RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);

     Request request = builder.sendRequest(content, new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
         //do some staff
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
              Response response) {

          //my methods
        }
     });
```

GWT version is 2.6 (if this is matter) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to disable clicking on other elements while response is completely received.

Just disable the widgets before sending the request to the server and make it enable once response is received back.

Please have a look at below post.

- [How to disable all widgets inside Panel or inside Composite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240775/how-to-disable-all-widgets-inside-panel-or-inside-composite)
- [Disable user interaction in a GWT container? using GlassPanel](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GlassPanel)

Find a demo here using [GlassPanel](http://google-web-toolkit-incubator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/GlassPanel/GlassPanelDemo.html)

---

Sample code using `GlassPanel`

*Attaching (displaying) your glass panel*

```
// Create a glass panel with `autoHide = false`
GlassPanel glassPanel = new GlassPanel(false);

// Attach (display) the glass panel
absolutePanel.add(glassPanel, 0, 0);

// Some time later remove (hide) the glass panel
glassPanel.removeFromParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you send your request, show a PopupPanel. This panel maybe empty, or you can add some nice spinner so that your users understand what is happening. This panel will cover the entire browser window and grey it out a little bit (you can change the glass properties if you want).

The best way, of course, is to create a widget out of this panel, so you can reuse it anywhere in your app without writing a duplicate code.

```
private static PopupPanel glassPanel = new PopupPanel();
...

glassPanel.setGlassEnabled(true);

glassPanel.show();
Request request = builder.sendRequest(content, new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
         glassPanel.hide();
         //do some staff
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
         glassPanel.hide();
         //my methods
    }
});
```